# TFS 2015 API - 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials

Tags: visual-studio, rest, api, tfs, tfs-2015

I am trying to call the REST API to get a previous builds details but when I try to run the script that calls the API, I get the error in the title:

> 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials

It's using the credentials of the Build Agent on the build server. The build server can see the TFS url because it's able to successfully build. And if I try to call the API using my credentials, it works. It just won't work with the account that the build agent is running under.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you check the agent pool and see what access/restrictions your build agent has?

Answer (score 1):

How did you set the Authorization in your script?

1. You can **[Use the OAuth token to access the REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/scripts/powershell?view=vsts#use-the-oauth-token-to-access-the-rest-api)**

> To enable your script to use the build process OAuth token, go to the
>   **Options** tab of the build definition and select **Allow Scripts to Access
>   OAuth Token**   (*Reference below screenshot to enable the option*).

Below script works on my side:

```
$url = "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/build/builds/14?api-version=2.0"
Write-Host "URL: $url"
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
}
Write-Host "$result = $($result | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 1000)"
```

---

2. You can also set the Authorization in script like below: (hardcoded your credentials in the script)

e.g :

```
Param(
   [string]$collectionurl = "http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection",
   [string]$projectName = "ProjectName",
   [string]$keepForever = "true",
   [string]$BuildId = "8",
   [string]$user = "UserName",
   [string]$token = "Password"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$uri = "$($collectionurl)/$($projectName)/_apis/build/builds/$($BuildId)?api-version=2.0"
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

Write-Host "$result = $($result | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 1000)"
```

[image]

Comment: The build agent can queue builds. That's not the issue. The same account that the agent using to build is getting that "unauthorized access" error when trying to access build information via the API (even though it was the same agent/account that initially triggered the builds).

Comment: @J.Doe OK, please see the updated answer, both the ways mentioned above working for me. you can have a try for that.

Comment: I am able to call the api and get the build details using my script. The script is working fine. The issue is that I can't do it with the user that the build is running under. If I hardcode _my_ credentials in the script, then it completely works. But if I remove the `-Credentials` flag (i.e. my credentials), then it uses the credentials of the user that is running the script (which is the build agent's user) and it fails. It needs to use those credentials, not mine. I thought maybe it's a permissions issue, but the build agents account is a Project Collection Administrator.

Comment: @J.Doe Yes, that's the expected behavior. The first method is just using the agents account, that should the solution in your scenario, just need to  `Allow the Scripts to Access OAuth Token`, Thus the agent account will use the `$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN` to call the REST API. Just try it.

Comment: @J.Doe If that still not work, then please add that agent account to agent pool (roles=>Agent Queue Administrators)

Comment: @J.Doe Have you added the `-Headers @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}` in your script?
 Could you please post your script in your original question for further troubleshooting?

Comment: @J.Doe Have you resolved the issue? any update? If the issue still existing there, could you please share your script for troubleshooting?

Comment: This worked for me: 
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
}