# Issue with accessing TFS Rest API

Tags: rest, api, azure-devops

I am trying to use the TFS REST API to automate a use case, Tried using PersonalAccessToken and System.AcessToken (provided by TFS) but getting unauthorized error.

When analyzed found that SSO is being used to authenticate with TFS, as it works when i try to access it from my browzer. My Question is how can I access REST API from a script ( Can be anything bash,shell, python..etc) protected by SSO

Any inputs will hep. Thanks

Comment: Can you share what did you try?

Comment: I tried the usual way to access any rest API that is using Basic Auth, Bearer token, personal access token. None of this work, have no clue how Auth works when sso is involved

Comment: Please share the code you tried.

Comment: Are you doing this through the build or release pipeline? Both have additional options `Allow scripts to access the OAuth token` which needs ticking to use `System.AcessToken`

Comment: I am doing that but still get unauth error

Answer (score 0):

Please try to disable the `Basic Authentication` for your TFS, then try it again.

[image]

If you want to run scripts by calling the REST API in build/release pipeline, then you can reference this SO thread : [TFS 2015 API - 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225499/tfs-2015-api-401-unauthorized-access-is-denied-due-to-invalid-credentials)

Comment: Yes I am trying to run in build and release pipeline but this also doesn't work. Getting below error    ...CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebExc 
2019-08-14T06:50:56.2183276Z    eption
2019-08-14T06:50:56.2183617Z     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Comment: Can you run the script locally? This seems a PowerShell issue, could you please share the PS script for further troubleshoot?